# How to get the img src , of the images created dynamically in casperjs?

Tags: image, dynamic, casperjs

The below code gets all the images present in the site and checks if the image has loaded in casperjs. The problem is i am not able to get the images which are created dynamically at run time. How do i do that?. Any help would be kindly appreciated.

1) The below code fetches the images which are static,it is not fetching the images which were created at run time.

```
var imagesArray = [];

function getImages() {
    var scripts = document.querySelectorAll('img[src]');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(scripts, function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('src');
    });
};

casper.start(url, function () {
    imagesArray = this.evaluate(getImages);
    var self = this;
    imagesArray.forEach(function (item) {
        if (self.resourceExists(item)) {
            self.echo(item + ' loaded');
        } else {
            var message = item + ' not loaded';
            self.echo(message, 'ERROR');
        }
    });
});

casper.run(function() {this.test.renderResults(true);});
```

2)I tried it using `waitForselector` as well, but it did not work.It said "wait time out occurred and the test case failed". Please see the code below

```
var imagesArray = [];

function getImages() {
    var scripts = document.querySelectorAll('img[src]');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(scripts, function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('src');
    });
};

casper.start(url);
casper.waitForSelector('.card-container', function() {
console.log("hi");
imagesArray = this.evaluate(getImages);
    var self = this;
    imagesArray.forEach(function (item) {
                if(self.resourceExists(item)) {
            self.echo(item + ' loaded');
        } else {
            var message = item + ' not loaded';
            self.echo(message, 'ERROR');
        }
    });
});


casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Image loading test finished');
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: From looking at your code, in your first example  it should be queryselectorall('img') instead of queryselectorall('img[src]')

Comment: @rusln: it does not make any difference, even if i change it to just img, it does not get the images which are rendered dynamically.

Comment: if you could give more information on how the images are loaded or the website itself, then we can find a solution. (in case you haven't solved it already)

Comment: @rusln: this is the site http://snapito.com/

Answer (score 2):

your function to get image sources looks fine - the problem obviously is that it runs before page gets modified. Try identifying if page gets modified at all (try different selectors, check Casper.options.pageSettings if it allows scripts to do their work).

```
casper.start(url);
casper.waitForSelector('.sticky-menu-active', function() {
    this.echo('...found selector ...try getting image srcs now...');
}, function() {
   this.echo('even after 10secs not found it - some scripts failed to execute on casperjs/phantomjs ?');
}, 10000);
casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('test finished');
    this.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of [each](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#each) and [waitFor](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor).  This may help (untested):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var images = [];

casper.GetImages = function() {
    images = this.evaluate(function() {
        var scripts = document.querySelectorAll('img[src]');
            return Array.prototype.map.call(scripts, function (e) {
                return e.getAttribute('src');
        });
    });
    this.echo('** Successfully got the images... **');
    return true;
};

casper.start(url);

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo('** Getting the images... **');
    this.waitFor(function check() {
        return this.GetImages;
    });
    this.each(images, function(self, image) {
        this.echo('Item loaded: ' +  image);
    });
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('** All done... **');
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help. but it did not solve my problem. It is not fetching the normal images also.it goes into the getImages function , but it is not returning anything. am trying to debug it.

Comment: You may need to run this code after pageload since the elements may not have been created yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it on `pageLoadFinsihed`. Try the below code(Untested)

```
var imagesArray = [];

function getImages() {
    var scripts = document.querySelectorAll('img[src]');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(scripts, function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('src');
    });
};

casper.start(url);
casper.on('load.finished', function () {
console.log("hi");
imagesArray = this.evaluate(getImages);
    var self = this;
    imagesArray.forEach(function (item) {
                if(self.resourceExists(item)) {
            self.echo(item + ' loaded');
        } else {
            var message = item + ' not loaded';
            self.echo(message, 'ERROR');
        }
    });
});


casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Image loading test finished');
    this.exit();
});
```